# cucumber converts string to integer?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I am doing some BDD but i've come across an issue i can't solve.
I am trying to write this as my gherkin line that's visible in the step defintions:

```
When the user has 2 overdue books where the fine is payed (fine is 0)
```

But the text comes out to

```
the user has {int} overdue books where the fine is payed \\(fine is {int})
```

i've tried to escape with a backslash in front of the character and stringified the integers but that just converts them to strings.

Comment: What are you expecting the "0" in "fine is 0" to be?

Answer (score 2):

Cucumber is being helpful by suggesting what it thinks you might want your step definition to be. You don't have the follow it. This is also a valid cucumber-expression:

```
the user has 0 overdue books where the fine is payed \\(fine is 0)
```